# Как при помощи библиотеки yup в JavaScript (react) сделать кастомную валидацию? Например, поле инпута может включать буквы и некоторые спец. Символы

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как при помощи библиотеки yup в JavaScript (react) сделать кастомную валидацию? Например, поле инпута может включать буквы и некоторые спец. Символы. Я подозреваю, что нужно использовать addMethod, но как с ним работать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Дорогой друг, а зачем вообще для валидации использовать библиотеки? У поля input есть такой отличный аттрибут как `pattern` - `<input type="text" pattern="[А-Яа-я]{1,30}" />`

Comment: в pattern нам необходимо писать регулярное выражение, которое , никакой здравый человек не захочет писать) а с библиотекой это "выражение" можно описать более декларативно, используя набор методов библиотеки) просто надо разобраться с этими методами

Answer (score -2):

Для создания кастомной валидации с использованием библиотеки yup нужно использовать метод `addMethod`.

Пример:

```js
import * as yup from "yup";

// Создаем схему валидации
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  username: yup.string().myCustomValidator(),
});

// Добавляем кастомный валидатор
yup.addMethod(yup.string, "myCustomValidator", function (message) {
  return this.test("my-custom-validator", message, function (value) {
    // Здесь мы можем реализовать любую логику валидатора
    if (!value) {
      return false;
    }
    const regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]*$/;
    return regex.test(value);
  });
});

// Используем схему для валидации объекта
schema.validate({ username: "test1234$" }).catch(function (err) {
  console.error(err.errors);
});
```

В данном примере мы добавляем новый метод `myCustomValidator` для типа данных `string`, который проверяет, что строка содержит только буквы и некоторые специальные символы. Для этого используется функция `test`, которая принимает имя теста (`my-custom-validator`), сообщение об ошибке и функцию-валидатор.

Функция-валидатор возвращает `true`, если значение проходит валидацию, и `false`, если не проходит. В данном примере мы проверяем, что значение совпадает с регулярным выражением, которое определяет допустимые символы.

После этого мы создаем схему валидации и используем ее для проверки объекта. Если значение не проходит валидацию, будет выброшено исключение с сообщением об ошибке.

Comment: А вы знали что GPT запрещен?

Comment: @anton по стилистике ответ, конечно, похож на то что GPT выдаёт, но я бы не был так категоричен, учитывая историю аккаунта.

Comment: @DiMithras а я бы был :) на то есть причины. Но пусть автор вопроса решает.

Comment: @aepot я имею ввиду, что он не строчит по 20 ответов в минуту :) Иначе смысл его использовать? Но, на карандаше, да.